# Which estimate of parameter is better in regression?

Tags: regression, self-study, variance

Suppose my true Model is:

$$y = Xb + u  \tag 1$$

But I am estimating:

$$y = Xb + Zd + u  \tag 2$$

I can get the estimate of $b$ from $(2)$ by using $Mz$ operator as:

$$\hat{b} = (X'MzX)^{-1}(X'MzY)$$

Why is an estimate from the first equation is better than the second?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @gung done. Thanks any help though?

Comment: I am sure you know the variance covariance matrix for $b$ when estimating model (1)? There likewise is an expression for the variance of the coefficients corresponding to $b$ when estimating (2). Can you derive that one as well?